# Google Places textual search not reproducing the stable results (changes from time to time)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native

I have used textual search on Google Places API to search  the basketball courts in a particular location. For instance when I type 
*"San Jose, CA, United States"*
it produces varied results from time to time.

What might be the issue? I have spent hours trying to fix this issue. But couldn't get any clue at all...
Please see difference between these screenshots.

Listing same as I type "basketball courts in **San Jose, CA, United States**"

[image: Listing same as I type "basketball courts in **San Jose, CA, United States**"]

Listing varies after a period of time

[image: Listing varies after a period of time]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post an exact request for Places API? Do you specify the location and radius parameters? Is the location and radius the same value in your examples?